# Prompt updates git branch only when sourced

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I tried to integrate the current git branch in my prompt, but it doesn't behave as expected. I'm using bash on ubuntu 16.04 and git 2.7.4.
When I start a terminal nothing of git is shown. If I source my `.bashrc` from inside a repository the branch is shown, but doesn't update anymore. This is what I wrote in my .bashrc:

```
green="\[\033[01;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[01;34m\]"
no_color="\[\033[00m\]"
purple="\[\033[01;35m\]"

source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
export PS1="$purple\u $green$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") $blue\W $no_color \$ "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. It is not necessary to use prompt command. The bug arises due to a syntax error.

If I assign the content of PS1 with `""` in order to use my variables for the colors, it only executes the __git_ps1 function when `.bashrc` is sourced.

But when I assign the PS1 content within `''` and do it without variables for the color and instead write the codes out, it works as expected. And as I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247585/to-export-or-not-to-export-bash-ps1-variable) it seems to be better practice not to export PS1 to the environment.

So the solution looks like:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;35m\]\u \[\033[01;32m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") \[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[00m\] \$ '
```

However I would be curious to know, what's the reason for this. It works within `""` in macOS.